# LoadLibrary : pyinstaller :format messageW failed

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Created a simple app with PYQT5 and tried to compile it to .exe file, I created on window 10 pc and it works great there, but when I tried to move the software to Windows 7 ( with no python installed) it gave me this error :

[image]

here is my **main.py** file :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog

import aboutUs
import users_settings


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1332, 933)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/pos_logo.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:#a1d0f4;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.settingsToolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.settingsToolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.settingsToolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.settingsToolButton.setFont(font)
        self.settingsToolButton.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/cog-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.settingsToolButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.settingsToolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
        self.settingsToolButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.settingsToolButton.setObjectName("toolButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.settingsToolButton)
        self.toolButton_6 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.toolButton_6.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton_6.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.toolButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton_6.setStyleSheet("background:#fe3636;color:white;")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/close-window-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton_6.setIcon(icon2)
        self.toolButton_6.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
        self.toolButton_6.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.toolButton_6.setObjectName("toolButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_6)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.toolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.toolButton.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/calculator-5-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton.setIcon(icon3)
        self.toolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.toolButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.toolButton_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.toolButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.toolButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton_2.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/store-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton_2.setIcon(icon4)
        self.toolButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.toolButton_2.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName("toolButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.toolButton_3 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.toolButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.toolButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton_3.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/tree-structure-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton_3.setIcon(icon5)
        self.toolButton_3.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.toolButton_3.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.toolButton_3.setObjectName("toolButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.userSettingsToolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.userSettingsToolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setFont(font)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/conference-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setIcon(icon6)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setObjectName("toolButton_4")
        self.userSettingsToolButton.clicked.connect(self.open_user_settings)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.userSettingsToolButton, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1332, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_2.setObjectName("menu_2")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setIcon(icon5)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_2.setIcon(icon4)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_3.setIcon(icon3)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.userSettingsAction = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.userSettingsAction.setIcon(icon6)
        self.userSettingsAction.setObjectName("action_4")
        self.userSettingsAction.triggered.connect(self.open_user_settings)
        self.action_6 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_6.setIcon(icon1)
        self.action_6.setObjectName("action_6")
        self.action_7 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_7.setIcon(icon2)
        self.action_7.setObjectName("action_7")
        self.aboutUs_menu = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon7 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon7.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/favicon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.aboutUs_menu.setIcon(icon7)
        self.aboutUs_menu.setObjectName("action_8")
        self.aboutUs_menu.triggered.connect(self.open_about_us)
        self.action_9 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_9.setObjectName("action_9")
        self.action_10 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon8 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon8.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/phone-18-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.action_10.setIcon(icon8)
        self.action_10.setObjectName("action_10")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_3)
        self.menu.addAction(self.userSettingsAction)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_6)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_7)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.aboutUs_menu)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_10)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_2.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def open_about_us(self, checked=None):
        if checked is None:
            return
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.ui = aboutUs.Ui_Dialog()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()

    def open_user_settings(self, checked=None):
        if checked is None:
            return
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.ui = users_settings.Ui_Form()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Vision store manager - Innoventiq"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                      "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/images/images/logo_small.png\"/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                        "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/images/images/pos_logo_small.png\"/></p></body></html>"))
        self.settingsToolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "إعدادت عامة "))
        self.toolButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "خروج "))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "الحسابات"))
        self.toolButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المخازن و الفروع"))
        self.toolButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المدخلات"))
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "إعدادات الموظفين و المستخدمين"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ذهاب إلى"))
        self.menu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "من نحن"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المدخلات"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المخازن و الفروع"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "الحسابات"))
        self.userSettingsAction.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المستخدمين"))
        self.action_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "إعدادت البرنامج"))
        self.action_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "خروج من البرنامج"))
        self.aboutUs_menu.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "عن الشركة"))
        self.action_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "الرخصة الحالة"))
        self.action_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "الإتصال بنا"))


import rsc_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myStyle = 'Fusion'
    app.setStyle(myStyle)
    # The proxy style should be based on an existing style,
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and here is my `main.spec`:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['E:\\Innoventiq\\vision_manager'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
             ('dlls/api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll', '.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-core-console-l1-2-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll','.'),
('dlls/api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll','.'),

             ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='app.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main')
```

I used Pyinstaller to generate the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code, and if you fix them I think your problem would be solved:

First, you need to load your external files (like `*.ico` in your example) properly when you want to freeze your script as one file executable. I added the first icon you can add all your other icons like that, also you can find more about that in a related question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile).

Second I suggest you disable `UPX` first because sometimes it can't properly bring standard PyQt DLL files with your project.

Third, I highly recommend you to build your project on Windows 7, and because of that, you don't need to feed `api-ms-win*.dll` as data files.

And last but not least make sure that your build and target architecture are the same (X64 or X86) and you already installed [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) on your Win7 target.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
import os
import sys
import rsc_rc
import aboutUs
import users_settings


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1332, 933)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.resource_path(
            "./images/images/pos_logo.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:#a1d0f4;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.settingsToolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.settingsToolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.settingsToolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.settingsToolButton.setFont(font)
        self.settingsToolButton.setStyleSheet(
            "background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/cog-256.ico"),
                        QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.settingsToolButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.settingsToolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
        self.settingsToolButton.setToolButtonStyle(
            QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.settingsToolButton.setObjectName("toolButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.settingsToolButton)
        self.toolButton_6 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.toolButton_6.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton_6.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.toolButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton_6.setStyleSheet("background:#fe3636;color:white;")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(
            ":/images/images/close-window-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton_6.setIcon(icon2)
        self.toolButton_6.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
        self.toolButton_6.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.toolButton_6.setObjectName("toolButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_6)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.toolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.toolButton.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(
            ":/images/images/calculator-5-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton.setIcon(icon3)
        self.toolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.toolButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.toolButton_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.toolButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.toolButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton_2.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/store-256.ico"),
                        QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton_2.setIcon(icon4)
        self.toolButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.toolButton_2.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName("toolButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.toolButton_3 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.toolButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.toolButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton_3.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(
            ":/images/images/tree-structure-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton_3.setIcon(icon5)
        self.toolButton_3.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.toolButton_3.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.toolButton_3.setObjectName("toolButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.userSettingsToolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.userSettingsToolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setFont(font)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setStyleSheet(
            "background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(
            ":/images/images/conference-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setIcon(icon6)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setToolButtonStyle(
            QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setObjectName("toolButton_4")
        self.userSettingsToolButton.clicked.connect(self.open_user_settings)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.userSettingsToolButton, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1332, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_2.setObjectName("menu_2")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setIcon(icon5)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_2.setIcon(icon4)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_3.setIcon(icon3)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.userSettingsAction = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.userSettingsAction.setIcon(icon6)
        self.userSettingsAction.setObjectName("action_4")
        self.userSettingsAction.triggered.connect(self.open_user_settings)
        self.action_6 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_6.setIcon(icon1)
        self.action_6.setObjectName("action_6")
        self.action_7 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_7.setIcon(icon2)
        self.action_7.setObjectName("action_7")
        self.aboutUs_menu = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon7 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon7.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/favicon.png"),
                        QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.aboutUs_menu.setIcon(icon7)
        self.aboutUs_menu.setObjectName("action_8")
        self.aboutUs_menu.triggered.connect(self.open_about_us)
        self.action_9 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_9.setObjectName("action_9")
        self.action_10 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon8 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon8.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(
            ":/images/images/phone-18-256.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.action_10.setIcon(icon8)
        self.action_10.setObjectName("action_10")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_3)
        self.menu.addAction(self.userSettingsAction)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_6)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_7)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.aboutUs_menu)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_10)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_2.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def open_about_us(self, checked=None):
        if checked is None:
            return
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.ui = aboutUs.Ui_Dialog()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()

    def open_user_settings(self, checked=None):
        if checked is None:
            return
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.ui = users_settings.Ui_Form()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate(
            "MainWindow", "Vision store manager - Innoventiq"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                      "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/images/images/logo_small.png\"/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                        "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/images/images/pos_logo_small.png\"/></p></body></html>"))
        self.settingsToolButton.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "إعدادت عامة "))
        self.toolButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "خروج "))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "الحسابات"))
        self.toolButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المخازن و الفروع"))
        self.toolButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المدخلات"))
        self.userSettingsToolButton.setText(_translate(
            "MainWindow", "إعدادات الموظفين و المستخدمين"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ذهاب إلى"))
        self.menu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "من نحن"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المدخلات"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المخازن و الفروع"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "الحسابات"))
        self.userSettingsAction.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "المستخدمين"))
        self.action_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "إعدادت البرنامج"))
        self.action_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "خروج من البرنامج"))
        self.aboutUs_menu.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "عن الشركة"))
        self.action_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "الرخصة الحالة"))
        self.action_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "الإتصال بنا"))

    @staticmethod
    def resource_path(relative_path):
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
        return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myStyle = 'Fusion'
    app.setStyle(myStyle)
    # The proxy style should be based on an existing style,
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Spec file (I also enabled console for better debugging):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['E:\\Innoventiq\\vision_manager'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
             ('dlls/api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll', '.'),
             ('./images/images/pos_logo.png','./images/images/')
             ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='app.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               name='main')
```